# Facebookログインでemailが取得できない

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

初めまして。
大変悩んでいることがあり、お力添えいただきたく思います。
現象　→　利用しているもの　→　検討したこと　→　質問　の順に書かせていただきます。

**現象：**
Facebookログインで、プロフィールが獲得できるがメールが獲得できない。

**利用しているもの：**
php-graph-sdk
https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/tree/master/docs

**検討したこと：**

3つあります。

１、アクセストークンは取れているかどうか
→　取れていました。var_dump($accessToken);exit;で確認しました。
→　さらに、上述のように、プロフィールは取れています。

２、そもそも

```
fb->get('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name', $accessToken);
```

はあっているかどうか。
→　あっているようです。
→　GraphAPIexplorerで確認したところ、メールアドレスは取れました（メールアドレスの権限を許可しました）

3、そもそも、そのアカウントがメールアドレスを弾いているのでは？
→　弾いてないようです。
→　自分のアカウントの　設定→アプリとウェブサイト　からビズリーチやDMM、CAMPFIREなどで確認したところ、メールアドレスを提供してました。しかし、自分のアプリだけには提供してませんでした。
→　ちなみに、そのアプリとの連携を削除して再度Facebookログインをしても結果は変わりません。

**質問：**
・他に検討することはありますでしょうか。
・解決方法をご存知でしたら教えていただきたく思います。

この問題に悩まされています。
どうか知恵をお貸しいただけませんでしょうか。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 解決しました。　
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/blob/master/docs/reference/GraphNode.md#getemail あたりで取得できたのでは？